# changes to templates not showing on server

Tags: templates, plugins

I have done some changes to woocommerce changes to its template in /MyTheme/woocommerce/templates, it shows fine on my localhost but when I upload the woocommerce to my server under my theme it doesn't show the changes and shows the original woocommerce plugin templates. The file structure is same but its not showing. What can be the reason? How to debug it?

Comment: Are you using a caching plugin?

Comment: @vancoder nope i am not

Comment: Woo provides a commercial support option. Have you tried that route?

Comment: @ChipBennett nope, but i would like to know when copying templates from plugin folder, should i paste it under abc/woocommerce/templates, where abc is my theme name?

Answer (score 0):

After many attempts, i had to make changes to the core template files in directory plugins/woocommerce and it worked, for safety i then copied the woocommerce/templates to mytheme/woocommerce/templates and surprisingly it worked! strange but at least it did.

Answer (score 0):

The official documentation says:

"To overide the admin order notification, copy: woocommerce/templates/emails/admin-new-order.php to yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/admin-new-order.php "

I was also poking around with it.. and for some people it doesn't work.. so they just dump all woo template files in the root theme directory. and presto it works :)

Try to omit that /templates/ directory..